# Sending POST/PUT via AJAX using casperjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs, casperjs

Is it possible to 'POST' or 'PUT' a JSON object to an API with Casperjs?

I can successfully do a GET call to my API. I just can't seem to get a POST/PUT to work.

I am trying to send a JSON object to my website through the API I have setup.  I am using the newest version of Casperjs and am setting --web-security=no through the command line.  I read the documentation but have found no place to add header values to the AJAX call.  I see there is an "options" parameter but the following doesn't work.  I know the JSON and the URL are all correct because I have tried it with the chrome extension postman.  I just can't seem to figure out how to add headers.

```
try {
    return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX("url to API", 'POST', jsonObject, false, 
         {
            dataType: "json",
            headers:{
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }
         }));
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Nothing is returned in the try/catch.  If I print the JSON.parse it is just HTML from my webpage asking for proper headings.

I have tried different variations of settings and even tried passing nothing. For Example:

```
try {
    return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX("url to API", 'POST', jsonObject, false, null));
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Still no luck.

Comment: You could register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events to see what is going on.

Comment: `casper.on('remote.message', function(msg){}`
and 
    `casper.on( 'page.error', function (msg, trace) {}`
Are not returning anything.  The AJAX goes perfectly fine but for some reason I can not set any headers (or I am setting them incorrectly)

Comment: What headers do you need? You can only set `overrideMimeType` and `contentType` judging from source code.

Comment: Just `contentType : application/json` but I've tried it with it like that and with the `headers` tag in the example.  Have others been successful with POST and PUTs using casperjs's client utils?

Comment: Where did you see the ability to set `overrideMimeType`? I can't see it anywhere in the documentation on CasperJS's site.

Comment: It's in the [code](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/modules/clientutils.js#L772). If it really worked from the browser, then you can compare the difference between the requests from browser and from casper with a proxy or wireshark.

Comment: Ahh, wireshark, I'll try that and see what goes through.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a proper content type with the proper settings key. So this should work. If your server endpoint expect only JSON in the request body, then you need to serialize it first.

```
return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX("url to API", 'POST', JSON.stringify(jsonObject), false, 
{
    contentType: "application/json"
}));
```

;

Comment: This didn't work either.  I got the same results that I used in my question.

Comment: Maybe you need to stringify.

Comment: I've tried JSON.stringify and the different setting options.  I'm wondering if anyone else has been successful with doing POST and PUTs.  If they have, did they mess around with the settings parameter.